# Execute commands from a single column of an input file

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipeline

I have very little experience with bash, but am attempting to put together a pipeline that reads in and executes commands line by line from an input file. The input file, called "seeds.txt", is set up like so

```
program_to_execute -seed_value 4496341759106 -a_bunch_of_arguments c(1,2,3) ; #Short_description_of_run
program_to_execute -seed_value 7502828106749 -a_bunch_of_arguments c(4,5,6) ; #Short_description_of_run
```

I separated the #Short_descriptions from the commands by a semi-colon (;) since the arguments contain commas (,). When I run the following script I get a "No such file or directory" error

```
#!/bin/bash

in="${1:-seeds.txt}"

in2=$(cut -d';' -f1 "${in}")

while IFS= read -r SAMP
    do
    $SAMP 

done < $in2
```

I know that seeds.txt is getting read in fine, so I'm not sure why I'm getting a missing file/directory message. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you have lots to do, you could get **GNU Parallel** to do them in parallel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try as below with `eval`...not very safe though, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) for more info

```
while read line; do eval "$line" ; done < <(cut -d';' -f1 seeds.txt)
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want. In this case, where I'm the only one making the seeds.txt file, it seems like the safety concern with `eval` is less of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
cut -d';' -f1 seeds.txt | parallel
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to avoid `eval`

```
while read -ra line; do command "${line[@]}"; done < <(cut -d';' -f1 seeds.txt)
```

Note this solution does not work if the program/utility is not an executable within your PATH, e.g. you wan to use a function or an alias. Not sure if the eval solution can do that too. Kudos to the `cut` solution!